# Converting JSONObject to JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am having an Java Object which consist many type of variables including a JSONObject.
Whan i debug my object i got the following String for JSONObject:-

```
{"INCLUSIONS":{"OPTIONS":[{"display":"Complimentary stay for children under 5 without extra bed"}]}}
```

But when i used:-gson.toJson(JSONObj),I got following

```
{"myHashMap":{"INCLUSIONS":{"myHashMap":{"OPTIONS":{"myArrayList":[{"myHashMap":{"display":"Complimentary stay for children under 5 without extra bed"}}]}}}}}
```

Someone please can elaborate why it is converting JSONObject to Map & list ??
Or Any work Around ??

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the Java code you've written for this as you appear to be using myHashMap as a variable that's being used in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `myJsonObj.toString()` instead of `myJsonObj.toJSON()`

Your problem happens because a JSONObject is stored as a HashMap to allow the programmer to reach values with methods based on keys. As example,

```
String jsonStr = "{'key': 'value'}";
JsonObject json = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class);
String value = json.get("key").getAsString();
```

You can figure that json attributes are stored as a `HashMap<JsonElement>`